# What is the best strategie to send complex data with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I have some informations in a form to send to the server as a (complex) array (or Object if you prefer) with JS/jQuery. (jQuery 1.7.2)
I'm thinking about JSON to solve the problem smartly. My code works right now, but i want to know if its possible to do it better.

So this example is pretty typical (The data are more complex irl) :

```
dataSend = { 'id': '117462', 'univers': 'galerie', 'options' : { 'email': 'hello@world.com', 'commenataire': 'blabla', 'notation' : '4' } };

$.ajax({
  url: "/ajax/ajaxMavilleBox.php",
  data: JSON.stringify(dataSend),
  success: function(x){
      smth();
  }
});
```

In an another context, i have to make the exact same thing without JSON.

With the same example :

```
dataSend = { 'id': '117462', 'univers': 'galerie', 'options' : { 'email': 'hello@world.com', 'commenataire': 'blabla', 'notation' : '4' } };

$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax/ajaxBox.php",
    data: $.param(dataSend),
    success: function(x){
        smth();
    }
});
```

Obviously, I missing something.

The url is :

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/ajax/ajaxBox.php?id=117462&univers=galerie&options=%5Bobject+Object%5D
```

And the url should be :

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/ajax/ajaxBox.php?id=117462&univers=galerie&options[email]=hello@world.com&options[commenataire]=blabla&options[notation]=3
```

There is any easy way to do it (I hope I don't have to edit the data myself in a loop or something)

**Edit : Solution for the second part**

Ok, the last part without JSON is correct. In fact, i was using an older version of jQuery in my page. 
$.param is not so good with jQuery < 1.4

More information here [Param Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

Comment: Any reason you're not using POST?

Comment: What does it change ?
I'm using GET just to see what happens. In production, it will be in POST.

Comment: There's a browser limit to how long the url can be, so you may run into issues if your object gets too large.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The url limit is approx 2000+ characters, so there is no problem with it in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned by @Johan `POST` shouldbe used here instead of `GET`
you can view data you are sending by using the Developer options in the browser you are using just press f12
also make sure you are using `jquery >= 1.4`
the incorrect serialized string in the url is the way that `$.param()` used to serialize prior to 1.4 version

Comment: "also make sure you are using jquery >= 1.4"

Exacty

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest setting the `type: 'POST'`, otherwise you will have a data limit eqvivalent of the browsers query string length.

If you use the post method, you should send the data as a json-string. Something like:

```
data: { DTO: JSON.stringify(dataSend) }
```

You need to use [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) if `window.JSON` is undefined (like in ie7 for example).

If you are using PHP on the serverside, you can fetch the object using:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['DTO']); //will return an associative array
```

or ASP.NET

```
public class DataSctructure
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string univers { get;set; }
    //etc...
}

var data = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form['DTO'];

DataSctructure ds = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DataSctructure>(data);

//properties are mapped to the ds instance, do stuff with it here
```

Comment: @jrummell Noticed that after i wrote the .NET explanation. I'll leave it there, might be useful for someone else :)